# Porting Trickle to android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, shared-libraries, porting

I am trying to port  Trickle (https://github.com/mariusaeriksen/trickle) on android.

What I have figured out till now is that I need to cross-compile the individual libraries that this application depends on, primarily 'libevent', using NDK standalone toolchain.

Got some help from this article- 
http://warpedtimes.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/building-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk/

I have managed to cross-compile libevent with the following 'build_android.sh' script:

---

```
export ANDROID_ROOT=/home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/include

#Since it complains about crtbegin and crtend

ln -s $ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
ln -s $ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtend_so.o


./configure \
--host=arm-linux-androideabi \
CC=$ANDROID_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-  androideabi-gcc \
LD=$ANDROID_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld \
AR=$ANDROID_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar \
RANLIB=$ANDROID_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib \
CPPFLAGS="-I$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/" \
CFLAGS="-nostdlib" \
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/" \
LIBS="-lc -lgcc -L$ANDROID_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8"
```

---

Now when i do the same for the trickle application, I get the following error on running the same script as above inside trickle project directory-

---

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for working aclocal-1.4... missing
checking for working autoconf... missing
checking for working automake-1.4... missing
checking for working autoheader... missing
checking for working makeinfo... missing
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ld used by /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld
checking if the linker (/home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-g++... arm-linux-androideabi-g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether arm-linux-androideabi-g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -E
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-g77... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-f77... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-xlf... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-frt... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-pgf77... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-fort77... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-fl32... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-af77... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-f90... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-xlf90... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-pgf90... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-epcf90... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-f95... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-fort... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-xlf95... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-ifc... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-efc... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-pgf95... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-lf95... no
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gfortran... no
checking for g77... no
checking for f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for f90... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
checking command to parse /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm -B output from /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-ar... /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib... /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip... arm-linux-androideabi-strip
checking if /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc static flag  works... yes
checking if /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc linker (/home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by arm-linux-androideabi-g++... /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld
checking if the linker (/home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the arm-linux-androideabi-g++ linker (/home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld) supports     shared libraries... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if arm-linux-androideabi-g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if arm-linux-androideabi-g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the arm-linux-androideabi-g++ linker (/home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld) supports   shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib... (cached) /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for gethostbyname in -lnsl... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for err in -lc... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking if libc defines __progname... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking err.h usability... yes
checking err.h presence... yes
checking for err.h... yes
checking time.h usability... yes
checking time.h presence... yes
checking for time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking asm/poll.h usability... yes
checking asm/poll.h presence... yes
checking for asm/poll.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for u_int64_t... yes
checking for u_int32_t... yes
checking for u_int16_t... yes
checking for u_int8_t... yes
checking for in_addr_t... no
checking whether /home/narayan/installations/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc needs -traditional... no
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for socket... yes
checking for strlcat... yes
checking for strlcpy... yes
checking for daemon... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for strsep... yes
checking for sendfile... yes
checking for libevent... yes
checking if underscores are needed for symbols... no
checking if we can access libc without dlopen... no
checking if we can access libc with libc.so... no
checking if we can access libc with /usr/lib/libc.so*... no
configure: error: Couldn't figure out how to access libc
```

---

The corresponding lines in configure.in are -

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING(if we can access libc without dlopen)
AC_TRY_RUN(
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *dh;

    dh = (void *)-1L;

    if (dlsym(dh, "printf") != NULL || dlsym(dh, "_printf") != NULL)
        exit(0);

    exit(1);
}, [AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)
    AC_DEFINE(NODLOPEN)
    HAVEMETHOD=yes], AC_MSG_RESULT(no), AC_MSG_RESULT(no))

if test "$HAVEMETHOD" = "no"; then
    dnl ugly, ugly hack          
    LIBCGUESS=`echo /lib/libc.so.*`
    USRLIBCGUESS=`echo /usr/lib/libc.so*`

    if test "$USRLIBCGUESS" = "/usr/lib/libc.so.*"; then
       USRLIBCGUESS=""
    fi

    if test "$LIBCGUESS" = "/lib/libc.so.*"; then
       LIBCGUESS=""
    fi

    for TESTLIB in libc.so `echo $USRLIBCGUESS` `echo $LIBCGUESS`
    do
        AC_MSG_CHECKING(if we can access libc with $TESTLIB)
        AC_TRY_RUN(
        #include <dlfcn.h>
        #include <stdio.h>

        int
        main(int argc, char **argv)
        {
            void *dh;

            if (dlopen("$TESTLIB", RTLD_LAZY) != NULL)
                   exit(0);

            exit(1);
        }, [AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)
            AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED(DLOPENLIBC, "$TESTLIB")
        HAVEMETHOD=yes], AC_MSG_RESULT(no), AC_MSG_RESULT(no))

    if test "$HAVEMETHOD" = "yes"; then
       break
    fi
    done
fi

if test "$HAVEMETHOD" = "no"; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR(Couldn't figure out how to access libc)
fi
```

I have tried the official NDK documentation but couldn't get much help.

So I have a couple of questions:-

1. How to resolve the above error?
2. How to tell the compiler to link the shared library (libevent) that i have cross-compiled for android earlier so as to generate the final executable command line app for android.

And also that is it even possible to port trickle on android?

I would be delighted if I could get some help or at least links to some articles which would help me out with this problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi  have you got the trickle cross compiled? I meet the `Couldn't figure out how to access libc` too, but cann't find a way to workaround.

Answer (score 0):

For 1., you need at least to adapt configure.in to modify the "ugly, ugly hack" (as sated in the source comments) part:

```
LIBCGUESS=`echo /lib/libc.so.*`
```

to

```
LIBCGUESS="/path/to/ndk/platforms/android-${ANDROID_API_LEVEL}/arch-${TARGET_ARCH}/usr/lib/libc.so"
```

Instead of using android-19, you should use the API level that corresponds to the minimum one you want to support.

Also, if you want to better support more Android devices, you should adapt the rest of your script so it can easily cross-compile your lib for other architectures as well (right now the NDK supports arm, mips, x86).

For 2., you can add `--with-libevent=/path/to/libevent_library/` parameter to the call to `./configure`. In this case, inside `/path/to/libevent_library`, you should have `./lib/libevent.so` and `./include/event.h`

Comment: I had already tried updating the LIBCGUESS to point to the correct API in my NDK folder but the result was same.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I guess I need to run autoreconf in order to make the changes made to configure.in be effective.

Also, I tried running that 'dlopen()' block in configure.in in isolation (in separate c file) to make sure it does check for libc. The test were positive for libc.so.6 installed in the system but failed for NDK Android API 19 libc.

Comment: I don't know much automake, but I guess so. Looking at the source again, the test is "AC_TRY_RUN" that will run the compiled code.. on your host. That can't work when cross-compiling. https://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_269.html

Comment: thanks for '--with-libevent'. I found it in configure --help :). And regarding minimum API, since trickle uses 'LD_PRELOAD', API>14 is required as far as I know. And the way android allows us to use 'LD_PRELOAD' is a bit different than in unix, so the source code of trickle would need to be modified.

But before that, I need to make sure that I can cross-compile trickle for android-arm-eabi.

Comment: that did help. I believe either I would have to heavily modify configure.in or would have to do away with the trickle build system and write Makefiles and use ndk-build. thanks.